# Reactive Spring Security: AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException after successful authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Probably the answer to my question is easy and I am missing something simple, but I have searched all around the internet and tried to debug this error for weeks, without any progress.

I have registered a filter in the reactive spring security config, this filter is executed at the authentication level, and its purpose is to validate a JWT token present in the authentication header. So it's the typical JWT authentication pattern.

The JWT validation, by itself, works properly. It is able to validate a JWT token, check if it is expired, wrong, valid, and so on. This is visible by printing the SecurityContext object:

> SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=UserDetailsDTO(id=2, username=peppe2, password=null, email=peppe2@yopmail.com, roles=[ADMIN], isEnabled=true, isLocked=false), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]]

And also the Authentication object:

> UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=UserDetailsDTO(id=2, username=peppe2, password=null, email=peppe2@yopmail.com, roles=[ADMIN], isEnabled=true, isLocked=false), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]

But, no matter what I do after the authentication filter, I receive a `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException` in the *ServerHttpSecurity* error callback. Here is the full stack trace:

> catalog-svc      | 2021-09-13 13:52:41.753 ERROR 1 --- [     parallel-3]
> a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [8415b576-2]  500 Server Error for HTTP PATCH "/users/1"
> catalog-svc      |
> catalog-svc      | org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: Not Authenticated
> catalog-svc      |  at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.commenceAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:70) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
> catalog-svc      |  Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
> catalog-svc      | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ it.polito.ecommerce.catalogservice.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP PATCH "/api/v1/users/1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
> catalog-svc      | Stack trace:
> catalog-svc      |      at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.commenceAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:70) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
> catalog-svc      |      at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.lambda$filter$1(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:45) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$32(Mono.java:3564) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2062) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2062) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:197) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:344) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:391) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:36) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:84) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2399) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2067) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> catalog-svc      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> catalog-svc      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> catalog-svc      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> catalog-svc      |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> catalog-svc      | Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
> catalog-svc      |  at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$0(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
> catalog-svc      |  Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
> catalog-svc      | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
> catalog-svc      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> catalog-svc      | Stack trace:
> catalog-svc      |      at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$0(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]
> catalog-svc      |      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar!/:3.4.7]

While here is the SecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity,
        authManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager?
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {

        return http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint { swe, e ->
                // The error is caught here
                Mono.fromRunnable {
                    swe.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
                    throw e
                }
            }.accessDeniedHandler { swe, e ->
                Mono.fromRunnable {
                    swe.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN
                    throw e
                }
            }.and()
            .addFilterBefore(
                jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter,
                SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().build()
}
```

and, in the end, the jwt filter:

```
@Component
class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(
    private val jwtUtils: JwtUtils,
    @Value("\${application.jwt.jwtHeader}") private val jwtHeader: String,
    @Value("\${application.jwt.jwtHeaderStart}") private val jwtHeaderStart: String
) : WebFilter {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val authorizationHeader= exchange.request.headers[jwtHeader]?.get(0)
        if (authorizationHeader != null) {
            val jwt = authorizationHeader.removePrefix("$jwtHeaderStart ")

            if (jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                val detailsFromJwtToken = jwtUtils.getDetailsFromJwtToken(jwt)
                val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    detailsFromJwtToken,
                    null,
                    detailsFromJwtToken.authorities
                )
                ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)
            }
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange)
    }
}
```

My questions are: how do I solve this problem? If you can't help me solving this, do you know any way to improve the stacktrace in Spring Reactive? Because I am not getting any hint for debugging.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a custom jwt filter when there is already one built into spring security? Whats the point of including a security framework if you not intend to use it?

Comment: @Toerktumlare in which part of Spring security is already implemented a jwt filter? All the projects that I saw use OAuth or OAuth2, which I don't mean to use

Comment: read the documentation for spring security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture instead of reading outdated and faulty blogs. You are aware that JWT is just a type of token. The authentication you are trying to implement is oauth2 that is using JWT tokens. JWTs are just a tole-type. Please read up on what oauth2 is, what JWT tokens are, and how spring security actually works, so you understand the problem before asking on stack overflow.

Comment: Toerktumlare, Before make no sense answer , read what is jwt and what’s oauth2. I hope after 2 years you got more professional knowledge and more communication culture to be polite with people. Question is fully correct and author has to go deep and find which filter after custom filter changes response status code